# How to make an image stretch in different screens

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

I have a divider with the ID `#divider`. I use Elementor to edit my wordpress website and fix stuff with CSS. It looks well on certrain screens, but I just checked it on my laptop and it won't stretch to the the edges. It's wide is 1278 px.

Also it seems to push another text column somehow. On elementor it appears just fine.
[image]

Comment: Can you please give image width to 100% ? Like #divider img {width:100%}

Comment: Hi Ashkar, it's not working. Here's a link where you can see the dividers:
http://berko.createak.co.il/

I've checked a few laptops and it won't stretch. Also, it caused another issue with pushing one of the text columns to the left (The one with the basketball net background image). I have no idea how to fix it. It appears just fine on the Elementor plugin. I attached a screenshot to the main question/

Comment: I have seen you have given `max-width: 100%` to that image and not `width`. If you add `width: 100%` to it, it seems to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your website and the following code seemed to work fine when I tried it via developer tools:

```
.elementor-image img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is here

```
<img width="1400" height="75" src="http://berko.createak.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Divider-2.png" class="attachment-full size-full" alt="" srcset="http://berko.createak.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Divider-2.png 1400w, http://berko.createak.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Divider-2-300x16.png 300w, http://berko.createak.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Divider-2-768x41.png 768w, http://berko.createak.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Divider-2-1024x55.png 1024w">
```

your image width is set to 1400 this will override whats in your styling sheet.

you can remove width="1400" or if that not possible use

```
.elementor-image img {
    width: 100%!important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, by any chance could you check what's wrong with my text column that's being pushed to the left as you can see in the screenshot in the first post?  I thought it has to do with the divider.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following and I managed to achieve full width for images..
1. Row -> Extend section and Content full width
2. The image itself -> Style -> Width -> Set VW to 100.

That's all I did and it worked.